# Exporting asynchronous populated data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, export

I want to export an object which gets populated by an async function, but as the function is async it exports the object before it gets even populated.

```
let map = {};
async function which populates the map;
module.exports.state = map;
```

I'm certain that the function populates the map before it gets called in the imported file. so what should my approach be!?
and I'm getting the empty object.

Comment: Exporting `map` in that context is just wrong. Export the async function that populates the map and make it return a Promise holding `map`. Use `map` **after** the async function has been called and the result is acquired, otherwise it is meant to be empty, that's intended.

Comment: I understand, but the async function is a heavy process, which doesn't just populate the map, so i can't export it!

Comment: No problem, then just export a function that returns a `Promise` that gets resolved only once the `map` is evaluted, hence when the async function finished.